# Math rendering in Apple Mail

Tags: mac, email, latex, apple-mail, mathjax

Is there any way to render mathematical expressions in `Apple Mail`? I am not looking for full `LaTeX` functionality but just to render short expressions like $x^2 + y^2 = \pi$ etc.

[Math formulas in email](https://superuser.com/questions/536569/math-formulas-in-emails#_=_) has something similar but they are okay with the application being non-Apple Mail & I'm looking for solutions with Apple Mail only (I keep the app open 24*7). It is mentioned on the question that :

> For example, I have heard that both Thunderbird and **Apple Mail** will support MathML for received mails, but Outlook will not.

Also, the comment by `Elliot G` dated Feb 6, 2021 on `Toad Hall`'s answer mentions that :

> Just adding to this (a bit late): I tried this and **it did render for me in Apple mail**, but macOS and iOS. However, it is definitely not full mathjax, as you cannot use environments like \begin{align}, etc.

But I haven't been able to find a way to make it work in Apple Mail. Can anyone help me with the process? I'm using MBA M1 with macOS 11.3.1.

Comment: Might be better asked over on https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @spikey_richie tried, didn't receive any answers!